# Store all tags in artists[i]['tags']

Tags: python, json

I have the code below to get the artists tags (genres) from last fm api. Each artist can have many tags like:

```
 {'artist': {'tags': {'tag': [{'name': 'alternative', 
  'url': 'https://www.last.fm/tag/alternative'}, {'name': 'indie', 
  'url': 'https://www.last.fm/tag/indie'}, {'name': 'electronic',
  'url': 'https://www.last.fm/tag/electronic'}]},
```

I want to store all the tags of a artist in the `artists[i]['tags']`. The issue is that I'm just getting the last tag with this code:

```
for artist in artist_data['artist']['tags']["tag"]:
    tags = artist["name"]
    artists[i]['tags'] = tags
print(artists[i])
```

more related code:

```
artists = {}

for i,v in artists.items():
    chosen = artists[i]['name'].replace(" ", "+")
    artist_response = requests.get('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&format=json&artist='+chosen+'&api_key='+api_key)
    artist_data = artist_response.json()

    for artist in artist_data['artist']['tags']["tag"]:
        tags = artist["name"]
        artists[i]['tags'] = tags
    print(artists[i])
```

Do you know how to store all the tags in the `artists[i]['tags']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing `artists[i]['tags']` with new `tags` in every loop.
You may want to append to it like this:

`artists[i]['tags'].append(tags)`

You must create `artists[i]['tags'] = []` before loop.